# Removing comments using Perl

Tags: perl

Something I keep doing is removing comments from a file as I process it.  I was was wondering if there a module to do this.

Sort of code I keep writing time and again is

```
    while(<>) {
        s/#.*// ;
        next if /^ \s+ $/x ;

        **** do something useful here ****
    }
```

**Edit** Just to clarify, the input is not Perl. It is a text file of my own making that might have data I want to process in some way or other.  I want to beable to place comments that are ignored by my programs

Comment: Remember that every octothorpe doesn't necessarily introduce a comment in Perl, e.g., `s###`, `m##`, and `qw##`.

Comment: Or more likely: `say "my favorite irc channel is #perl"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question does not make clear what type of file it is. Are we dealing with perl source files? If so, your approach is not entirely correct - see gbacon's comment. Perl source files are notoriously difficult (impossible?) to parse with regex. In that case, or if you need to deal with several types of files, use Regexp::Common::comment as suggested by Niffle. Otherwise, if you think your regex logic is correct for your scenario, then I personally prefer to write it explicitly, it's just a pair of strighforward lines, there is little to be gained by using a module (and you introduce a dependency).

Comment: @leonbloy You are probably right that it is hardly worth wrapping it up in a module.  I have a reflex reaction not to repeat code, maybe I am taking this too far.

Answer (score 5):

Unless this is a learning experience I suggest you use [Regexp::Common::comment](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Regexp-Common/lib/Regexp/Common/comment.pm) instead of writing your own regular expressions.

It supports quite a few languages.

Comment: How can I use this library since I'm new to Perl could you please give some examples?

Comment: It fails because of false positives.